# Fetching Google calendar events on embedded system (api secret?)

Tags: google-oauth

I am developing software that will be used on small system at clients. The software is fetching Google calendar events from whatever Google account the client adds to it. The thing is that Googles API requires an secret key to work. As it is now, the system is working but the key is directly in the code, which means that the end user will be able to see it.

Firstly, is this a problem? I guess that because the key is "secret", there will be bad if a client can see it. Second, if this is bad, how should I do to avoid this? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should not be a problem since the key alone is not enough to generate an access token. You also need a refresh token or authorization code for that.

One risk is that, using the key, one of your clients (Alice) builds an OAuth authorization URL and tricks another of your client (Bob) into authorizing Alice's custom application to get calendar data. That problem only occurs if you're using the "installed application" workflow with the "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob" redirect URI.

If you want to avoid this problem, you can decide to host a web service that will handle the authorization for the embedded system. This web service will hold the client secret, and will receive call from your systems to either request authorization from a customer or refresh a token. Of course now you need to secure this web service, but you can probably do that with a customer-specific set of credentials. That way the only thing on the customer's premises are his specific credentials to access the webservice, nothing else.

Comment: What is the authorization code? In my script I have a client id, a client secret and a scope, all provided by Google API and that information is also available for the end user. Is client id and authorization code the same?

Comment: The authorization code is what Google provides to your application once the use gives you his permission to access his data. It's either manually copied by the user to a text box in your application, it the user if redirected to your application with the code in the url's query string.